# What will happen if the number of threads in a warp are less than 32?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I read that the number of threads in a warp can be 32 or more. why is that? if the number is less than 32 threads, does that mean the resources goes underutilized or we will not be able to tolerate memory latency?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The number of threads per warp is exactly 32 on all supported CUDA hardware, past and present.

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs clarification - perhaps you are confusing the CUDA "warp" and "block" concepts?

Regarding warps, it's important to remember that warp and their size is a *property of the hardware*. Warps are a grouping of hardware threads that execute the same instruction (these days) every cycle. In other words, the size width indicates the SIMD-style execution width, something that the programmer can not change. In CUDA you launch blocks of threads which, when mapped to the hardware, get executed in warp-sized bunches. If you start blocks with thread count that is not divisible by the warp size, the hardware will simply execute the last warp with some of the threads "masked out" (i.e. they do have to execute, but without any effect on the state of the GPU/memory).

For more details I recommend reading carefully the [hardware and execution-related sections of the CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#simt-architecture).